# how to insert single checkbox value in coldfusion code

Tags: coldfusion

I have a single checkbox, I want that when I check the checkbox it 
        should insert 1 else 0 in the database. How can I do that? This was 
        earlier a radio button field which is getting converted to check box so 
        already entry in the database is working good, I am posting my database 
        code as well.

```
    <tr>
            <td class="leftFormLabelCell extrasmalltextbold" style="border-
             left:1px solid ##9c9c9c;" width="15%">
             #mocTrans.Translate("Required template Action Item?")#
            </td>

            <td>
               <input type="checkbox" name="reqtempactionitem" value="0">
            </td>
    </tr>
    Databse code: 
    <cfif StructKeyExists(URL, "reqtempactionitem") and 
     IsBoolean(URL.reqtempactionitem)>
    , #reqtempactionitem#
    <cfelse>
    , 0
    </cfif>
```

Comment: you have `value="0"`. You typically set value to `1`. If checked, you get `1` in you variable; else StructKeyExists returns false.

Comment: I am not able to understand the proper code for this, can you help me with this what should help me to insert my values please?

Comment: Hey, Thankyou  Bernhard Döbler my code is working now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The way html checkboxes work is that if checked, the browser will submit `[checkboxname]=[value]` to the webserver. If the box is *not* checked, the browser *does not submit anything at all* to the server.

So the easiest solution uses `cfparam`, which will give the submitted checkbox a default value.

Thus, in your html, you should have:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="reqtempactionitem" value="1">
```

(As has been noted in comments, your value was 0 and should be 1.)

Then, in the database code:

```
<cfparam name="reqtempactionitem" default="0">
...
dbfield = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_bit" value="#reqtempactionitem#">
```

Note the use of `cfqueryparam`, which is strongly recommended in all queries for both performance and security reasons.

Comment: <tr>
             <td class="leftFormLabelCell extrasmalltextbold" style="border-
              left:1px solid ##9c9c9c;" width="15%">         
              #mocTrans.Translate("Required template Action Item?")#
       </td>
         
     <td>
  <input type="checkbox" name="reqtempactionitem" value="1">
     </td>
  </tr>
For Database code:
         <cfif StructKeyExists(URL, "reqtempactionitem") and           IsBoolean(URL.reqtempactionitem)>
 , <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_bit"    value="#reqtempactionitem#">
 <cfelse>
  , 0
 </cfif>

Comment: but it's entering 1 only in the database, I want when I check this checkbox I should get 1 else I should get 0. How can I do that, can you please check my code I have wasted my day in this.