# Boolean checkbox in ColdFusion

Tags: checkbox, coldfusion

I am trying to code a checkbox which should store boolean values in the database when checked or unchecked. Precisely I want only one checkbox and when it is checked I get 1 in the database else I store 0. How can I get that using ColdFusion? I have wasted a lot of time on this but no luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to insert single textbox value in cold fusion code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45159889/how-to-insert-single-textbox-value-in-cold-fusion-code)

Comment: That's my question that I had put up but it did not give the correct output so I have reposted it today. any suggestions will be much appreciated. ThankYou

Comment: You should include the code that you tried. What you were expected and what you got instead.

Answer (score 2):

You'd create a checkbox in your html with a value of 1.  Let's call it 'MyCheckbox'. As you probably know, when you post a form that has an unchecked checkbox, nothing about that checkbox is included in the form data.  One approach to dealing with that is to param the value on the back end.  So if your form posts to formpost.cfm, then at the top of that file, you'd:

```
param boolean form.MyCheckbox = 0;
```

That way, form.MyCheckbox would always have a value, 0 or 1, which you'd then insert into the database.

Another approach is to have a hidden form field that stores the 'real' checkbox value, and use js to bind the click event on the checkbox element to a function that updates the hidden field value based on the checkbox's checked attribute.

Comment: Whenever you use `cfparam`, make sure to specify the `type` to ensure the data assigned to that variable is of the correct data type. Don't do the hidden form field thing, that's just unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Name your checkbox field. When checked, it will pass through the form. Then just use a `structKeyExists()` to pick it up.

```
x = structKeyExists(FORM,"checkboxName")?1 (or sanitized checkbox value):0
```

Comment: Why the downvotes? What is wrong with either my or Dave's answer?